# File stubbornly refuses to allow me to edit in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing

I opened up a shapefile ZIP in QGIS. Now, I cannot "toggle editing mode" to on, nor access any of the editing features, anymore! What could I be doing wrong?

[image: See below.]

Please, and also the one, here-for, this:

[image: sxz]

Comment: Please try with QGIS 2.18. I've also had some trouble with editing vectors in the latest versions.

Comment: Try to extract or unzip the folder before adding it.
If you are using Windows computer, right click on the zipped file and extract it to a location of your choice. Then go to QGIS and load the shapefile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extract it from the zip - zipped shapefiles are read only in QGIS

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say, but the file might be read-only.

In any case, you can try exporting the layer as a new file - possibly of a different type (like GeoJSON) - and see if you can edit that.